# Effective simulation of large scale Modelica models by automatic translation to Modia

Tags: julia, modelica

this is more of an hypothetical question, but might have great consequences. Lot of us in Modelica community are dealing with large scale systems with expensive simulation times. This is usually not an obstacle for bugfixing and development, but speeding up the simulation might allow for better and faster optimizations.

Recently I came across [Modia](https://modiasim.github.io/docs/) possibilities, claiming to have superb numerical solvers, achieving better simulation times than Dymola, a state-of-the-art Modelica compiler. The syntax seemed to cover all important bits. Recreating large scale component models in Modia is unfeasible, but what about automatically translating the flattenized Modelica to Modia? Is that realistic? Would that provide a speed up? Has anyone tried before? I have searched for some

This might also hopefully improve integration of Modelica models and postprocesssing / identificaiton tooling within one language, instead of using FMI or invoking a separate executable.

Thanks for any suggestions.
For those interested, we might as well start developing this.

Comment: We have automatically translated the OpenModelica front-end to Julia and then combined that with some Julia backends (MKT and DifferentialEquations.jl). This is work in progress but we hope to release something soon. We have some papers on it, let me know if you are interested.

Comment: Wow, sounds cool! Werent aware, that you are following this behind the scenes. Excited to see the release.

Comment: Interesting question through I am wondering how far the promising speed-up would be and why. May be you would like to view this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65548832/what-does-impact-a-simulation-runtime-in-modelica/65551568#65551568

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We in the Modia team agrees that the modeling know how in Modelica libraries must be reused. So we are working on a translator (brief details given in https://ep.liu.se/ecp/157/060/ecp19157060.pdf) from Modelica to Modia. The plan is to initially provide translated versions of Modelica.Blocks, Modelica.Electrical.Analog and Modelica.Mechanics together with Modia.

Comment: Seems like the whole gang is here :) Thats great. Though I was aiming at maybe simpler translation of flattenized Modelica, the work you suggest will eventually cover the whole Modelica language, right?

Still, have you considered translating just the flattenized Modelica first to spread the impact faster? Am I right that this should be simpler, or not?